# Magento 2 product share in instagram and twitter and get the response after share

Tags: magento2, social-buttons

I would like to get the response after the product share in instagram and twitter in magento2 product page.

I am getting the response for Facebook like below code:

```
require([
"jquery"
], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
var product_url = $('#product_url').val();
var product_id = $('#product_id').val();
var product_name = $('#product_name').val();
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      // init the FB JS SDK
      FB.init({

            appId      : '',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
            channelUrl : product_url, // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
            xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
          });

          // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
           var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    function fb_share() {
        FB.ui( {
            method: 'feed',
            name: "Facebook API: Tracking Shares using the JavaScript SDK",
            link: product_url,
            picture: "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/557969.png",
            caption: "Tracking Facebook Shares on your website or application is a useful way of seeing how popular your articles are with your readers. In order to tracking Shares, you must used the Facebook JavaScript SDK."
        }, function( response ) {
            if (jQuery.type(response) != 'undefined') {
               $.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                //url: '',
                data: { product_id: product_id, product_name: product_name},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json'
              }).done(function (data) {
              });
                //$("#fb_successresult").append("<b> Appended text</b>");
            }else{
                //$("#fb_failresult").append("<b>Not Appended text</b>");
            }
        } );

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('button.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
    });
        });
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify. You want to be notified after someone shares a link to page on your website on Twitter or Instagram ?

Comment: I would like to add the share button in product page and get the response after share

Comment: Apologies. What kind of response?

Comment: Product Shared response, Whether product is shared or not.

Comment: if you have any links plaese suggest me.

Comment: Please find the updated question, iam getting the response to facebook like above.

Comment: Hi @Dominic Xigen any answers